# How do I create an operator in Haskell?

Tags: haskell-platform, haskell, haskelldb

Making a ternary logic table, and I would like to make my own function for an operator that I'll call `<=>`.

So, for example, I want to do this, but that isn't right.  what's the correct way to do this?

```
data Ternary = T | F | M
deriving (Eq,  Show, Ord)

<=> :: Ternary -> Ternary -> Ternary
<=> T F = F
<=> T T = T
<=> T M = M
<=> F F = T
<=> F T = F
<=> F M = M
<=> M F = M
<=> M T = M
<=> M M = T
```

Comment: Just as a side note, `M <=> M` should be `M` rather than `T`. But that depends on your "Maybe" semantics.

Comment: Don't forget that you can set arity and associativity by using `infixl`, `infixr`...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just add parentheses around your operator:

```
(<=>) :: Ternary -> Ternary -> Ternary
(<=>) T F = F
(<=>) T T = T
(<=>) T M = M
(<=>) F F = T
(<=>) F T = F
(<=>) F M = M
(<=>) M F = M
(<=>) M T = M
(<=>) M M = T
```

This turns it from infix form to prefix form. Alternatively, you can just use infix in the definition:

```
(<=>) :: Ternary -> Ternary -> Ternary
T <=> F = F
T <=> T = T
T <=> M = M
F <=> F = T
F <=> T = F
F <=> M = M
M <=> F = M
M <=> T = M
M <=> M = T
```

Comment: Is there a way to create something like the `:` cons operator? The `:` cons operator has this special feature where it considers everything on the right hand side to be a list. I've been trying to recreate the `:` operator, but it always requires parentheses on the right hand side.

Comment: @ClarkGaebel: perhaps it might be interesting to mention `infix` as well?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You can do the same thing yourself the following way: `data List a = Nil | a :- List a` and then the crucial part: `infixr 5 :-`. Doesn't have to be 5, but that is the precedence of lists, just has to be `infixr` and NOT `infixl` or `infix`. `infixl 9` is the default

Answer (score 12):

Function names with symbols have different syntax than those without:

```
-- Works:
(<^>) :: Int -> Int -> Int
a <^> b = a + b

-- Doesn't work:
{-
<^> :: Int -> Int -> Int
<^> a b = a + b
-}

-- Works:
letters :: Int -> Int -> Int
letters a b = a + b

-- Doesn't work:
{-
(letters) :: Int -> Int -> Int
a letters b = a + b
-}
```

I promise, though - Haskell is well worth learning the complex rules.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify (line-wise) the definition as follows:

```
(<=>) :: Ternary -> Ternary -> Ternary
T <=> T = T
F <=> F = T
M <=> M = T
M <=> _ = M
_ <=> M = M
_ <=> _ = F
```

Comment: That doesn't look simpler to me.

Comment: That's why I have a `(line-wise)` in there. Clarity is debatable though. I can see the code better because I am forced to deduce what it actually does as opposed to looking at a raw tabulated definition. But that's me.

Comment: IMO it is simpler, I can quickly see that if they are equal then return true, if they aren't but one is a maybe, then return maybe, if they aren't equal and don't involve a maybe then return false. Only part that I might find surprising is the `M <=> M` being `T` part.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `Eq` and `Ord`, you can do the following:

```
data Ternary = T | F | M
deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

(<=>) :: Ternary -> Ternary -> Ternary
x <=> y = if x == y then T else max x y
```

If you do happen to change it so that `M <=> M == M`, then you can do the following:

```
data Ternary = M | T | F
deriving (Eq, Show, Ord, Enum)

(<=>) :: Ternary -> Ternary -> Ternary
x <=> y = fromEnum $ rem (toEnum x * toEnum y) 3
```